# How to upload files using testRigor when i don't have an input type=file?

Tags: web-testing, testrigor

i'm using testRigor to make webstesting in our software but we have this screen where we can click to open the upload box or we can drag the file there to upload it:

[image: upload .XML file]

How can I make testRigor find this input to 'drag' the file if [here in the documentation](https://testrigor.com/docs/language) we have this information:

> The file upload is supported out of the box. Just use it like the
> following:

```
enter "<FILE_URL>" into "fileField"
```

It's said that this command 'enters' the file URL into the type=file input but as you can see in the image, I don't have this type of input to put the file.

Thanks!

Comment: _" but as you can see in the image, I don't have this type of input to put the file"_ - Yes, you have!

Answer (score 2):

> It's said that this command 'enters' the file URL into the type=file input but as you can see in the image, I don't have this type of input to put the file.

Checking on the image you share, you have that type of input there:

```html
<input id="file-input-cd730" accept="text/xml" hidden type="file">
```

With that said, first thing you need is to upload your desired file to some cloud storage system. The file needs to be accessible by testRigor.

Then you can do

```
enter "<url-to-mentioned-file>" into "file-input-cd730"
```

if you want to do a file upload.

Now if you want to do a drag and drop considering your sample page is:

```html
<div class="file input dropzone ">
    <label for="file-input-cd730" id="ember568" class="file-upload ember-view">
        <input id="file-input-cd730" accept="text/xml" hidden type="file">
        "Arrastre um arquivo para cá ou clique aqui para escolher um arquivo"
    </label>
</div>
```

you can do

```
drag file "<url-to-your-file" into "dropzone"
```